# Want to select data from different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in database, named **users**(store user details) and **posts**(store post details). Now i want to get data from both tables. Like user_image from **users** and post description from **post**.

I am using this query

```
SELECT * FROM `users`AS u,`posts` WHERE u.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM `posts`)
```

But it returns duplicate data. I have 2 users and 3 posts but it returns 6 posts.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
Select a.user_image, b.post_description from users as a join posts as b on a.user_id = b.user_id
```

Do an inner join & you shall get the desired result

In the above query a & b are alias for the two different tables. I you do not want to use alias you can also write it as users.user_image in your select statement.

Write the fields you want from both the tables in your select statements.

The below image will help you understand the inner join

[Inner Join Circle for understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jL9F.png)

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
Select * FROM user u right join posts p on u.id = p.user_id
```

?

Comment: Or maybe with a JOIN

Comment: that would be too fancy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use group by as below:

```
SELECT * FROM `users`AS u,`posts` WHERE u.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM `posts`) group by u.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get data from both tables you need to use joins.and you make sure the two tables are interlinked by primary keys
so use this can help

```
select user_image,post_description from users join posts on users.user_id=posts.user_id;
```